# Regex pattern match how to leave one with spaces in it?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have the following example string :
**<ia:save-config xmlns:ia= "http://google.com/yang/ia" />**

Basically, I need a regex pattern that matches a string starting with **'<'** and ending with **':'** but with has no space in between. For eg in the above string I want to write a regex pattern so that it matches **'<ia:'** but not **'<rpc xmlns= "urn:'** since the second one has spaces in between.

I have the following regex pattern till now: **'<.*?:'** but it matches both above mentioned text..

Comment: Are you sure you mean any chars other than `<`, `:` and whitespaces between `<` and `:`? Or do you mean just letters, digits or underscores? Please have a look at the two solutions below, which one better suits your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The `.` matches everything except linebreaks, including < and :

You can use this:

```
<\w+?:
```

which matches alphanumeric characters (letters, numbers, and underscores) between the `<` and `:`.

Comment: If you want to match any character except space, you can use `<(.[^ ])*?:`.
The [^ ] means to not include space in the match.

Answer (score 0):

To match a substring between two different chars that contains no whitespace, you can use

```
<[^<:\s]*:
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mi75yE/1).

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `[^<:\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`, `:` and whitespace (`\s`)
- `:` - a colon.